# Convert a dictionary to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I have a dictionary in which values are `odict_items`:

```
{1: odict_items([('a', 0.0952), ('b', 14.583351), ('c', 120000), ('d', 6000)]),
 2: odict_items([('a', 0.098733336), ('b', 14.526156), ('c', 120000), ('d', 6000)])}
```

When I convert it to a dataframe the output is as follows:

`df = pd.DataFrame(dict.values())`

```
          0            1             2          3
0   (a, 0.0952) (b, 14.583351)  (c, 120000) (d, 6000)
1   (a, 0.0987) (b, 14.526156)  (c, 120000) (c, 6000)
```

But the desired output is as follows (first column is the key and the next columns are values in odict_items):

```
      a        b          c       d
1   0.0952  14.583351   120000  6000
2   0.0987  14.526156   120000  6000
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, 'index')`?

Comment: It changes the first column to be the key but it does not change the other columns: columns names and columns are still displayed as `(a, 0.0952)` where as I want `a` to be the column name (2nd column) and the value to be ` 0.0952` only.

Comment: Side note: you have 2 `c` keys for the first `odict_items`. The last one is probably `d`

Comment: Yeah last one is `d`. Corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reconstruct valid dictionaries from the items:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: dict(v) for k,v in dic.items()}, orient='index')
```

Output:

```
          a          b       c       d
1  0.095200  14.583351    6000     NaN
2  0.098733  14.526156  120000  6000.0
```

Used input:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
dic = {1: OrderedDict([('a', 0.0952), ('b', 14.583351), ('c', 120000), ('c', 6000)]).items(),
       2: OrderedDict([('a', 0.098733336), ('b', 14.526156), ('c', 120000), ('d', 6000)]).items()}
```